# How append li element inside a ul lists with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

How can I append a new `li` element on the right `ul`? Each card has a `ul` and a `form`.

When I submit the form I append a new `li` in the `ul`. Each `ul` contains `.topics` class. But this new `li` is being added over all cards.

I did't find a solution to append this li inside the ul where it was created.

**This is my HTML structure**

```
<div class="card" id="card1">
  <div class="card-body">
   <ul class="topics">
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
      <form method="post" class="topic-form">
          ....
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" id="card2">
  <div class="card-body">
   <ul class="topics">
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
      <form method="post" class="topic-form">
          ....
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And my JS code**

```
$('form.topic-form').submit( function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this)[0];
   $.ajax({
          ...ajax stuff...        
      },
      success: function (json) {
          form.reset();
          $(".topics").append('<li>.....</li>')
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which `.topics` you mean. Use `$(this)` in general (or `form` in your case) to target to right one.

```
$(this).closest('.card').find('.topics')
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that `form` is not a jQuery collection but a DOM element.

Comment: @PeterKA is right, so find function will throw an error

Comment: @ItaloLemos: I had there `$(this)` first, than I've changed to `form` because I saw your declaration `form = $(this)[0]` - I meant there is a jQuery object. If not, my fault :-) I've returned `$(this)` what was the first variant of my answer...

Comment: @pavel Tha's right, I checked right now and my declaration is incorrect, form = $(this)[0] is returning a JS object not a jQuery, so I have changed to form = $(this) and works! My bad

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line

```
$(".topics").append('<li>.....</li>')
```

...is acting without context, and searching globally. You need to restrict it to the `ul` related to the `form` that triggered the event. The most logical way would be to find the `form`'s nearest `.card` element and go back in from there.

```
$(this).closest('.card').find('.topics').append('<li>.....</li>')
```

Comment: in the success callback does `this` still refer to the just-submitted `form`? If not, then substituting `form` for `this` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First inside a submit make a reference to your form `$currentForm = $(this);` then use this last inside Ajax response to inser `li`

by search parent card then append into found topic as follow :

```
$currentForm.parents(".card").find('.topics').append('<li>.....</li>');
```

not that `parents()` start search with first parent element , when `closest()` start with the element it self , no such diffrence exept that .
so your ajax should look like

```
$('form.topic-form').submit( function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $currentForm = $(this);
      $.ajax({
            ...ajax stuff...        

       },
       success: function (json) {
            $currentForm.get(0).reset();
            // or $('form#myform').trigger("reset");
            $currentForm.parents(".card").find('.topics').append('<li>.....</li>');
      }
}
```

Here is a sample Snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $('form.topic-form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $currentForm = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        let rand = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5)
      $currentForm.get(0).reset();
        $currentForm.parents(".card").find('.topics').append(`<li>${rand}</li>`);
      }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width:45%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" id="card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <ul class="topics">
      <li>FOO from1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <form method="post" class="topic-form">
      <button>add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" id="card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <ul class="topics">
      <li>BAR form2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <form method="post" class="topic-form">
      <button>add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```